# IMFSourceReader - Decode and Re-sample audio in C#

Tags: c#, audio, ms-media-foundation, resampling

I am looking to decode and re-sample an audio file using IMFSourceReader in C#.

For example:

**I want to decode (MP3 to WAV) AND re-sample the bit rate (64Kbps to 192Kbps) of the following audio file -**

> MyAudioFile - 48KHz - 64Kbps.MP3

to -

> MyAudioFile - 48KHz - 192Kbps.WAV

I am trying to decode MP3 to WAV by specifying the partial media settings as in the code below, but it is not re-sampling the decoded WAV file:

```
var fileStream = ((MediaFoundationReaderRTSettings) settings).Stream;
var byteStream = MediaFoundationApi.CreateByteStream(fileStream);
var reader = 
MediaFoundationApi.CreateSourceReaderFromByteStream(byteStream);      

reader.SetStreamSelection(  
MediaFoundationInterop.MF_SOURCE_READER_ALL_STREAMS, false);
reader.SetStreamSelection(  
MediaFoundationInterop.MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM, true);

//Create a partial media type indicating that we want uncompressed PCM audio
var partialMediaType = new MediaType();
partialMediaType.MajorType = MediaTypes.MFMediaType_Audio;
partialMediaType.SubType = settings.RequestFloatOutput ? 
AudioSubtypes.MFAudioFormat_Float : AudioSubtypes.MFAudioFormat_PCM;

partialMediaType.SampleRate = 48000;
partialMediaType.BitsPerSample = 16;
partialMediaType.ChannelCount = 2;

// set the media type
// can return MF_E_INVALIDMEDIATYPE if not supported
reader.SetCurrentMediaType( 
MediaFoundationInterop.MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM, IntPtr.Zero, 
partialMediaType.MediaFoundationObject);

return reader;
```

Appreciate help on how to go about this with some example. Thanks!

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? According to MSDN the resampling functionality of the source reader is added in Windows 8.

Comment: Hi Anton, 

I am using Windows Phone 8.1. 

I am looking for an example in C# as to how can the re-sampling be done with MediaFoundation.